# How to use software built from source and installed with brew in the same project?

Tags: cmake, homebrew, macos-catalina

I am trying to get my head around package managers. I recently installed `llvm` in macOS using

```
brew install llvm
```

I installed `python3.8` using `pyenv` and `CMake` latest release from https://cmake.org/download/. Brew displayed this message after the installation:

```
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✘, python@3.8 ✘
Required: libffi ✔
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Should I be concerned that I did not install `CMake` nor `python3.8` using `brew`? I would like to know before replacing my previous `CMake` and `python3.8` installations with those offered by `brew`.
2. Is there a way to use pakages/software installed with `brew` and without it in the same project and not make everything a mess? If there is, how can I learn to do it?

I am a physics major so my knowledge in these topics is not as good as I would like to.

Thanks for the help!